# Crash on IF conditions check

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crash-reports

I have an app in the app store that mostly works fine. I'm getting some crash reports and the crash reports point to a line where IF conditions are checked. Thinking that it might be an 'error while unwrapping an optional value' thing I implemented a guard statement before the check and even entered double nil check in the if condition. But still... no game. It passes the guard statement and crashes on the if condition check.

Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Any thoughts? This is my code:

```
let offRoad = self.route?.offRoad ?? false
guard UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active && self.isFreeDrive != nil && self.route != nil else {
      return
}
if self.isFreeDrive ?? false && offRoad == false {   // this is the crash line
    // doing some stuff
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add parenthesis to your if? EG: `if ((self.isFreeDrive ?? false) && !offRoad) { ... }`
You can also add guard with let EG: `guard let freeDriver = self.isFreeDriver else { return }`

Comment: Didn't try that. Will do that for the next version. The thing is, it happens only very occasionally, which makes me think it could be memory related. But still very strange as in that case memory would have to be 'released' between the guard and if statement.

Comment: The parens shouldn't matter. Is it possible you're in a closure or background thread and "self" has been dereference?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I am in a background thread yes. But shouldn't is 'hang' in the guard statement then as I'm checking self.route != nil in there. Anyway, willing to give this a shot anyway. Can't hurt. How would I solve this? [unowned self] ???

Comment: If you use self in closure you have strong reference to it (self). To avoid retain circle you should use unowned or weak in closures. 
If isFreeDriver and route are properties, you can add `didSet { print(newValue) }` to monitore if your properties has change.

Comment: You could try doing `weak var weakSelf = self` Then using weakSelf and see if it helps, The fact that it occurs rarely might point to a weird corner case of self being dereferenced after guard but before if...though that seems a bit farfetched.

Comment: @DanielSumara Thanks. I'll give that a try. This actually would explain why it only happens sometimes. You see, this code is inside a delegate method from the CLLocationManager (didUpdateLocations). Usually self gets de-initialised (i check for that so no retain cycle... usually). But, what happens if I get a location update JUST at the time or JUST after self deinitialises? That would then cause the crash right?